# Frappe (ERP Next): How can we store null in a Currency Field of a DocType?

Tags: erpnext, frappe

We require null to be stored in a Currency Field of a DocType. Right now even though the field is not mandatory, by default 0 (zero) is stored in the database, whenever a row is inserted. Is it possible to store null (no value) for the Currency field? Or do we need to switch to Float for the same?

Answer (score 2):

The design for numerical properties is to be non-null. Can you explain the use case? Since Currency value are often used in expressions, functions, it does not make sense to keep them null.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Our use case is we have created custom doctype and have an input field which is optional for the user and zero is a valid input. And, the input field corresponds to an amount. Hence, we chose currency. As the input field is optional, we want to differentiate between user not entering any value(null) vs user entering "0" in the field. So, I suppose we will have to use float in this scenario.

Comment: Hi @rushabh-mehta , there are use cases ( for integer ) where the field is optional . So for a numeric field if it is not mandatory, the fact that a value is not entered should be indicated by a null value and not zero . In some cases zero may not be even a valid value so defaulting to zero is also not always appropriate. Databases support null values for numeric fields . So curious of what motivated this design for numerical properties